# IIS 7 Managed Code Administration API on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, windows-xp

I have to write a tool, that uses the IIS7 Managed Code Administration API. 
Unfortunately we still have Windows XP workstations and as I've googled so far it's not possible to install IIS 7 on Windows XP.

But what about just having only the IIS7 Managed Code Administration API installed on Windows XP? Is there a way to use them under Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research about, and it looks like it's not possible to install the Management Code Administration API on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to install IIS 7 on XP, you can manage it remotely, for example this is an app from Microsoft which does exactly what your app is supposes to do without the need to install IIS7 locally on the XP machine:

[Internet Information Services (IIS) 7 Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2299)

Comment: I need to write an automation tool, so I can't use the UI from Microsoft.

Comment: I know, it's clear from your question. I just wanted to show that you can build such tool with no need to install IIS 7 locally. there should be some APIs or assemblies you can use, some kind of IIS SDK or similar. I don't know the name or where to find those apis but I would start from MSDN or google for examples.